# Replit error: /usr/bin/env: ‘./python3’: No such file or directory after using PIP

Tags: python, replit

whenever I type, for an example: `pip install aiohttp==3.7.3`, it gives me: `/usr/bin/env: ‘./python3’: No such file or directory` is there any way to fix it? (The error is in REPLIT)

I had problems with using aiohttp in REPLIT, I tried uninstalling package files. I "reinstalled" packages, such as "aiohttp" after doing the problem referred to the title popped up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well and haven't been able to solve it.

In the meantime, I use `python3 -m` instead and it works:

```sh
python3 -m <module-name> <args>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, go to .replit and delete the Variable called `hidden = ["venv", ".config", "**/__pycache__", "**/.mypy_cache", "**/*.pyc"]`
after deleting, go to the file directly and download the module to your computer, then upload it to the file it's not in.
I hope this works,
-JKID_Tech

P.S. I tried this IT WORKS if you get python from your computer then go to the python files or try to find it on the internet for example PyPI

Comment: Then Find `./python` FILE